# Can I load saved ships from one game save into another?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

Say I designed and saved something cool in Career mode. Now I want to load and modify that ship in a separate Sandbox save.

Any saved ships don't show up. Only the Stock ones do.
Any possibility to import them somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is entirely possible, you just have to move the `.craft` file from one save folder to the other.  Inside the KSP directory, you should be able to find the ship you created in career inside the `$KSP$/saves/<save name>/Ships/` folder. Ships created in the space plane hanger will be in the SPH subfolder, while ships created in the VAB will be in the VAB subfolder.

Comment: Read in Butters's voice: neato!